# Authenticate Azure app service with AAD custom login in mobile app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services

I have created app service for mobile app. Then  i have added Authentication to the app service. Then Selected Authentication type as "Log on with Azure AD". It is working fine.

Is it possible to have custom login page instead of browser based login screen?

I was able to get the token by using https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token. But not able to authorize the app service with this bearer token.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have custom login page instead of browser based
>   login screen?

This page is the authentication endpoint of AzureAD. Though it can be configured by Company branding, I think it cannot be customlized by yourself for Moblie APP.

> I was able to get the token by using
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token. But not able to
>   authorize the app service with this bearer token.

Authencation/Authorization for Web App is a feature that **securing Web App behind those IDPs**, NOT just like other azure resources you can use REST API to access it.  I understand what you want to do . But this action is not recommended or supported.

Comment: Thanks @Wayne Yang - MSFT

Answer (score 1):

> I was able to get the token by using https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token. But not able to authorize the app service with this bearer token.

As juunas answered, your token may does not match the AAD provider you configured on Azure Portal. Details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication) to check your configuration. Moreover, you could use https://jwt.io/ to decode your access_token and validate the related properties (e.g. the `aud` should be the clientId you configured on Azure Portal,etc.).

As [App Service Authentication / Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) (EasyAuth) states as follows:

> Users who interact with your application through a web browser will have a cookie set so that they can remain authenticated as they browse your application. For other client types, such as mobile, a JSON web token (JWT), which should be presented in the `X-ZUMO-AUTH` header, will be issued to the client. The Mobile Apps client SDKs will handle this for you. **Alternatively, an Azure Active Directory identity token or access token may be directly included in the Authorization header as a bearer token.**

For Azure Web App or Azure Mobile App, you could just access your endpoint as follows:

```
https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/api/values
Header: Authorization:Bearer {the id_token or access_token of AAD}
```

Or

```
https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/api/values
Header: x-zumo-auth:{authenticationToken}
```

Moreover, if you retrieve the access_token in your mobile app, you could also use it to retrieve the `authenticationToken` and use the `authenticationToken` for communicating with the backend endpoint.

```
POST https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/{provider-name,for your scenario, it would be AAD}
Body: {"access_token":"<your-access-token>"}
```

For your mobile client, you could use the client for Azure Mobile Apps, details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library). Also, you could follow [Authenticate users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#authentication) to understand the client-flow and server-flow authentication for App Service Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

As Wayne Yang said, customization of the login page is limited to logos and some text.

I'm not sure if you can use the "Easy Auth" for APIs.
You might need to actually implement the authentication in your app.

In that case your API would validate the incoming JSON Web Token so that its signature is valid and that the audience and issuer are what is expected.
Most frameworks have JWT authentication available, so it mostly comes down to configuring that properly.